# Failing to alloc memory received by a pointer linux

Tags: c, pointers, struct, calloc

I have a function that receives by a pointer the location where will be stored. This place can have different other similar structs.The function has to read a file. This file have stored a struct, which i need to read.

```
typedef struct user_manage_t{
    short int user_id;
    char permission;
    long int other_id;
    long int check;
}user_manage_t;


typedef struct holder_t{
    user_manage_t *user_manage;
    user_manage_t *user_manage_backup;
    //(...)and a lot of stuff
}holder_t;

holder_t  holder;


int db_read_from_file(user_manage_t *prt){

    DEBUG_PRINT("READ_FROM file started");
    FILE *fd_read;
    char buffer[480];
    int read, bytesRead=0; 
    int num;
    const  struct user_manage_t *header;
    fd_read = fopen("/home/user/user_list","r+b");   
    if (fd_read == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        DEBUG_PRINT("Its open!!!");
    }
    do 
    {
        read=fread(buffer, 2, 90, fd_read);
        bytesRead=bytesRead+read;   
        DEBUG_PRINT("Number of bytes lidos read=%d",bytesRead);
    }while(read!=0); //(bytesRead < 480);
    header = (struct  user_manage_t *) (buffer);
    fclose(fd_read);
    if ( NULL == ( prt = calloc( 10, sizeof(user_manage_t))))//aloca
    {
        DEBUG_PRINT("MAJOR_ERROR: couldnt allocate mem to users");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy( (struct user_manage_t *) &prt, &buffer, 90); 
        DEBUG_PRINT("Users copied to main list");
        for ( short int i=0;i<4 ; i++ )
        {
            DEBUG_PRINT("i= %hd",i);
            DEBUG_PRINT("User id: %d",holder.user_manage[i].user_id );
            DEBUG_PRINT("Permission: %d",holder.user_manage[i].permission);
            DEBUG_PRINT("other_ID:%ld",holder.user_manage[i].other_id);
            DEBUG_PRINT("Check_value:%ld", holder.user_manage[i].check);
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
main(){

        db_read_from_file((struct user_manage_t *) &holer.user_manage); 
        db_read_from_file((struct user_manage_t *) &holder.user_manage_backup);
}
```

When I run the code I get SEGFAULT and valgrind tell me this,

> Thread 2:
>   ==2746== Invalid read of size 2
>   ==2746==    at 0x80523B4: db_read_from_file (code.c:3069)
>   ==2746==    by 0x20303333: ???
>   ==2746==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

This is the line of  "DEBUG_PRINT("User id: %d",holder.user_manage[i].user_id );" So obviously looks like I am not storing it in the right place.
Can u help me?

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause of your exact problem, but in `memcpy( (struct user_manage_t *) &prt, &buffer, 90);` you copy 90 bytes to the place where the `prt` pointer variable is stored, not to the place where it points to.

Comment: I believe sth has a point, that looks horribly wrong.

Comment: sth is right, that `memcpy` has to be corrupting memory, unless your pointers happen to be 90 bytes in size somehow... and perhaps consider checking `prt` for `NULL` pointers, too?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but I think I am allocating 10x sizeof(user_manage_t) which has 12 bytes, so a total of 120 bytes

Comment: @Kxp: `&prt` means address of `prt`, `prt` already is a pointer, so you're passing a pointer to a pointer to `memcpy`, so `memcpy` will overwrite whatever this pointer-to-a-pointer is pointing to, and it is pointing to a pointer, the one that holds the memory address of the actual struct. That mem address is what you are overwriting. And then some more memory, even!

Comment: @sth: don't you also get that icky feeling that all those casts are there to suppress compiler warnings?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Going by what you see here on Stack Overflow, that seems to be the most common use case for casts ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Priority Nr 1*
After looking at your code a bit more, I suspect you're casting as much as you do, because you kept getting compiler warnings about *"incompatible [pointer] types"* and the like. Those warnings exist for a reason: there's an issue, a possible source for bugs there. Don't hush it up, don't ignore it: *FIX IT!*

Yes, sometimes those casts are required, and sometimes compilers complain about your code when *you know what you're doing*. In that case, you can add a cast, but don't think of those casts as compiler-gags: they are ways to tell the compiler that you know what you're doing. You've just gone cast-crazy to get the compiler to shut up. That's bad.

*Next*
In both your `db_read_from_file` calls from `main`, you are passing pointer to a null pointer to your function. That means you still have to allocate memory to actually go and *store* that data, or you have to redefine `holder` to something like:

```
struct
{
    user_manage_t user_manage;//not pointers, actual structs
    user_manage_t user_manage_backup;
} holder;
```

If you keep them as pointers, just allocate all members of `holder` in main:

```
holder.user_manage = malloc(sizeof *holder.user_manage);//and so on
//preferably, though:
if (NULL == (holder.user_manage_backup = malloc(sizeof *holder.user_manage_backup))
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);//error
```

*The big one*
As sth already mentioned:

```
memcpy( (struct user_manage_t *) &prt, &buffer, 90);
```

You are passing `&prt`, which reads: address of `prt`. This variable in itself is already a pointer, the memory address of a pointer is, again, a pointer. A pointer to a pointer (double indirection, avoid if possible...). Now as if that weren't enough: look at what you pass to your function:

```
db_read_from_file(&holder.user_manage);
```

Keep in mind that `holder.user_manage` already is a pointer, you are passing a pointer to a pointer! Thats double indirection. Then, you pass a pointer to this pointer to a pointer to `memcpy`!! Yes, you may have to read this last sentence again. But in short: you are passing a pointer, to a pointer, to a pointer to a struct, where that last bit (the pointer to a struct) could just be a null-pointer, too!

So what you have is this:

```
memcpy(void ***, char *, 90);//where the prt is void ***, and **prt could be NULL
```

Think about memcpy as a function that, basically does this:

```
void * memcpy( void *target, const void *src, size_t nr_of_bytes)
{
    char *dest = target;
    char *from = src;//use char, as it is guaranteed to be 1 byte in size
    int i;
    while(nr_of_bytes--)
        *dest++ = *from++;//copy byte to destination, move pointer 1 byte
    return dest;//return destination
}
```

Notice that the destination is being dereferenced (`*dest++`). If you pass a pointer to a pointer(`&prt`), and dereference it, you end up with a pointer, right? That's what you are writing to => `*(&prt) == prt`!

The cast, and the way you use it suggest you believe you're writing to whatever `prt` is pointing to, while in fact you are trying to write 90 bytes to whatever the pointer to `prt` is pointing to. And it's pointing to `prt`, which in turn points to a pointer. Only after this third inderiction, we find the struct... that's just crazy.
Anyway, the size of a pointer is 4 bytes on a 32 bit system, 8 on 64 bits. You are copying *90* bytes, so you probably end up in memory you shouldn't mess with.

Replace your code with this:

```
memcpy(*prt, buffer, sizeof *prt);//copy max the sizeof whatever prt is pointing to
```

And change the `db_read_from_file` function to this:

```
int db_read_from_file(user_manage_t **prt)//pointer to pointer!
```

And keep in mind that, whenever you want to change something of the struct that `prt` points to (2nd level), you have to dereference it, to get a regular pointer. For example, allocating memory:

```
if ( NULL == ( prt = calloc( 10, sizeof(user_manage_t))))//aloca
```

Has to become:

```
if ( NULL == ( *prt = calloc( 10, sizeof(user_manage_t))))//aloca
```

However, this is still wrong in many ways. What you actually need, is `realloc`, because `prt` might already be pointing at allocated memory:

```
*prt = realloc(*prt, 10*sizeof **prt);
if (*prt == NULL)
    //ERROR
```

It's cleaner, and safer.

Also check if your function isn't being passed a null pointer, do away with needless casts (they're clutter), and always check the return value of functions!

Comment: Thank you for the help:)
But i still have a question/issue, In this code i specifed the size as 10x12bytes, but this changes when I start the program, plus I have no idea about the size beforehand, and there are other threads that may use this function, and i would prefer to do the malloc inside the function.
I already changed the code to check for nullprt

Comment: @Kxp: If you want to allocate the memory inside of the function, then you have'll probably need 2 levels of indirection, or return the allocated memory at the end...

Comment: Ohhhh...that was something that I was afraid of.
do u know any website that can help me understand how to do that?
Thanks a lot:)

Comment: @Kxp: Nips, you already have three! levels of indirection... that's just evil!

Comment: @Kxp: Just curious: did you add those casts because of compiler warnings?? -- You don't know how that works, but you're using multiple threads?? Basic memory management is just that: it's basic. Just google a couple of tuts to memory management, or do a search for _"learn C the hard way"_, it's a free on-line book

Comment: At some point it was because of warnings.
the program wasn’t suppose to need this, but now is a bit important.I know how it works with 1 level, but when gets to the 2nd level I have almost no experience, and that was also a reason to try this way.
I cant change the part  "user_manage_t user_manage;
    user_manage_t user_manage_backup;" because the sizes is changing every minute, I am constantly free'ing and malloc'ing this mem, also it would make me change the whole program that could take a few days:\
For now I am gonna read that book, and try to figure everything u said. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Kxp: well, for now, the easiest fix would be to change the function's  prototype to take a pointer to a pointer as argument (` **prt`), and add 1 line: `user_manage_t *p = *prt;`, then work with that `p` variable, it's a simple pointer, then you don't have to deal with 2 levels all the time

Comment: I think you manage to do it, It looks like that is working, I still have to check the part that writes to the file, but  it does what I wanted. thank you a lot Elias, and everyone that tried to help me:D
I am gonna post the final code to anyone that might need it.

Comment: @Kxp: You're welcome. Please do read the _help_ section of this site: users are requested not to post _"thank you"_ comments but mark the answer as accepted instead

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code, in case some one stumbles in a similar situaion:

```
typedef struct user_manage_t{

short int user_id;
char permission;
long int other_id;
long int check;
```

}user_manage_t;

typedef struct holder_t{

```
user_manage_t *user_manage;
user_manage_t *user_manage_backup;
pthread_mutex_t check_mutex;
pthread_mutex_t backup_mutex;
//(...)and a lot of stuff
```

}holder_t;

holder_t  holder;

int db_read_from_file(user_manage_t **prt, pthread_mutex_t mtx){

```
DEBUG_PRINT("READ_FROM file started");
FILE *fd_read;
char buffer[480];
int read, bytesRead=0; 
int num;
const  struct user_manage_t *header;
fd_read = fopen("/home/user/user_list","r+b");   
if (fd_read == NULL) 
{
    printf("Error");
}
else
{
    DEBUG_PRINT("Its open!!!");
}
do 
{
    read=fread(buffer, 1, 480, fd_read);
    bytesRead=bytesRead+read;   
    DEBUG_PRINT("Number of bytes lidos read=%d",read);
}while(read!=0); //(bytesRead < 480);
header = (struct  user_manage_t *) (buffer);
fclose(fd_read);
if ( NULL != prt )
{
   status = pthread_mutex_trylock (&mtx);
   if (status != 0)//compor isto
   {
         DEBUG_PRINT("ERROR with lock");
         return -1;
   }
   else
   {
        num = bytesRead / sizeof(user_manage_t);
        DEBUG_PRINT("prt is not null and num=%d",num);
        //should add an if to check if num >0
        //if ( NULL == ( *prt = calloc( num, sizeof(user_manage_t))))//aloca
        if ( NULL == ( *prt = malloc(bytesRead)))
        {    
             DEBUG_PRINT("MAJOR_ERROR: couldnt allocate mem to users");
             status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
             return -1;
        }
        else
        {
             //memcpy( *prt, header, sizeof(**prt));    
             memcpy( *prt, header, bytesRead); 
             DEBUG_PRINT("Users copied to main list");
             status = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);                 
             for ( short int i=0;i<4 ; i++ )
             {
                 DEBUG_PRINT("i= %hd",i);
                 DEBUG_PRINT("User id: %d",holder.user_manage[i].user_id );
                 DEBUG_PRINT("Permission: %d",holder.user_manage[i].permission);
                 DEBUG_PRINT("other_ID:%ld",holder.user_manage[i].other_id);
                 DEBUG_PRINT("Check_value:%ld", holder.user_manage[i].check);
             }
             return 1;
        }
    }
}
if ( NULL == prt )
{
    DEBUG_PRINT("Pointer is null!");
    return 0;
}
```

}

main(){

```
    db_read_from_file(&holer.user_manage, holder.check_mutex);  
    db_read_from_file(&holder.user_manage_backup, holder.backup_mutex);
```

}

I am not sure if I am checking  the null prt well, but the rest is working.
I made a small changes to be "perfect" is only missing thing is sending the filename as input of the function.It looks like the mutex is working with 100% sure.

Comment: `memcpy(*prt, buffer, sizeof(*prt));` is wrong; `sizeof(*prt)` is the size of the _pointer_ to the struct, not the size of the struct; use `sizeof(**prt)` instead.

Comment: Yes that part is wrong, but sizeof(**prt) only gives me 12 bytes, which is the size of 1 struct when num=1, but when num=3 it still gives=12, is it suppose to be like this? how I can have the total space of the allocated space?

Comment: Your latest edit (using `bytesRead`) is the right approach. `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time; it can get you the size of a single struct (since that is defined at compile time), but not the number of structs (since that is determined in runtime).