# Array inside struct filled with garbage after initialization

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization

I defined a data structure (`Foo`) that contains an array of 25 pointers (`members`) to itself. I want to initialize each of those pointers to `NULL`, but my init function isn't working correctly. When my `Foo f` returns from `foo_init()`, only some of the `members` are `NULL`, others are just populated with random values.

```
//in Foo.h
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Foo {
    struct Foo * members[25] ;
} Foo ;

void foo_init(Foo * f) ;

//in Foo.c
void foo_init(Foo * f) {
    f = (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));

    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 25 ; i++) {
        f->members[i] = NULL ;
    }
    /* Ok here, all members are NULL */
}

//in main.c
#include "Foo.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    Foo f ;
    foo_init(&f) ;

    /* why isn't every index of f.members NULL? */


    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```

I ran my code through LLDB. Inside foo_init(), all `members` are `NULL`. But after returning from foo_init(), `f.members` is full of random garbage values.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler complain about your code?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: I guess it should ...

Comment: It was a typo, sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: Why `malloc` into your class object?

Comment: You are allocating heap memory for something that was already declared on the stack in your first line in `foo_init`. Get rid of that line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324429/why-is-my-initialization-function-returning-null

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That one seems familiar somehow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address of the `Foo` in your `main` is immediately overwritten by the call to `malloc`. Just remove that line and your initialization should work.

If you really want `foo_init` to allocate memory you can convert it to :

```
void foo_init(Foo **out_f) {
    Foo *f = malloc(sizeof *f);

    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 25 ; i++) {
        f->members[i] = NULL;
    }

    *out_f = f;
}
```

Or simply `return` a pointer as it is idiomatic in C :

```
Foo *foo_init(void);
```

Comment: Did the compilator know the type of *f in moment of sizeof? Thx i learned something today :)

Comment: Can you please tell me why do you use a pointer to a pointer ```Foo **out_f```?

Answer (score 2):

Try this then

```
Foo *f ;
foo_init(&f) ;


void foo_init(Foo ** f) {
    *f = (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));

    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 25 ; i++) {
        (*f)->members[i] = NULL ;
    }
}
```

@TripeHound is right

Comment: Whoops, that was just a typo. My actual code already looks like     `Foo f ;`
`foo_init(&f) ;`

Comment: Which won't work because the first thing the function does is throw away the passed-in value and malloc a new structure.

Answer (score 1):

another option is to use a pointer to pointer if you want to allocate Foo inside foo_init(). This way f points to valid memory after returning from foo_init

```
void foo_init(Foo ** f) {
    *f = (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));

    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 25 ; i++) {
        (*f)->members[i] = NULL ;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Foo *f;

    foo_init(&f);

    return 0;
}
```